# What is the normal javascript jQuery naming convention for local variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variables like this:

```
function refreshGrid(xxx)

var yyy = $('#AccountID').val()
```

xxx is a function parameter and yyy is a local variable.

Can someone tell me what is the accepted naming convention. I understand there may be different ones but I am just looking for the one most commonly used.

Comment: Just give them useful names that will help you and others when it comes to maintaining the code, and try to keep a consistent style throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

Some people follow a convention that "jQuery objects are stored in variables with names starting with a `$`", but other than that, the usual convention is just "Variable names are descriptive".

Answer (score 0):

Local variables and function arguments just get meaningful names.  I've not seen any widely used or useful prefixing convention for either.  After all, there are no hard-wired types (as with notation like hungarian notation in C/C++) and the scope is local so it's not like outside agents need to know about these variables.

Variable names usually start with a lowercase letter and are more commonly camelcase such as `firstChild`.  It seems a lot more common with JS to see camelcase instead of underscores.

Feel free to look at any of the popular libraries to get some ideas for a consistent style.  For example, here's the jQuery source:   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes it's better to think of the worst variable names, which I started to do after reading about the [two worst variable names](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2004/03/the_worlds_two_worst_variable.html) awhile back, which are (according to the post):

1. `data`
2. `data2`

All variables store data, and `data2` is just lets us know you already used `data` already.

I've definitely been guilty of at least the first, with variants like `testdata`, `rawdata`, `theString`, etc.

On the other hand, I've also been known to make a simple `for` loop into a novel because I wanted to make sure every variable was totally meaningful.  And then I got to the next loop, nearly the same situation, and there I was with variable names like `moreMeaningfulName` and `counterOfBeans2`, not much better than `data2`.

Point being is that it should be as meaningful as it needs to be.  If you start using one letter iterators, you'll lose track, but in the end, they keep count and there will be another like it soon.

As far as function params, I've lately been trying to make it a habit to give the function a  name that implies it's job and it's params, when possible, so the param names are already obvious. Like `paymentSender(payment)` or `addUserToSchedule(user, schedule)`. Not always an option, but usually if I can't think of a function name, I can think of the params, or I know the function name but not the params, etc.

Comment: _"already used `data` already"_ Was this delicious irony deliberate? ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think `camelCase` is the most used, but we can't really know.